# Rails 4.2.1: ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.2.1 on a brand new Rails Application.
I keep getting this error when trying to create new user from console: **ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation**

I've been googling around for hours, but I'm stuck with this.

This is my command to create a new user from the console:

```
User.create(:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe", :username => "John", :email => "john.doe@gmail.com", :password => "password")
```

This is my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable, :omniauthable, 
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :polls
  has_many :settings
  has_many :stories
  has_many :story_followers

  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 300, too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
                             :large => "500x500#",
                             :medium => "250x250#",
                             :thumb => "100x100#"
                            }, :default_url => "avatarmissing.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/gif)
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to add the bio attribute to the create statement, tho I would expect a different error message for that.

Comment: Can you provide the actual stacktrace you receive?

Comment: I solved this one. By mistake I forgot to add a "presence: true" in a different Model.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with commenting out the validation a you have in place to help narrow down the issue. The error message points to an invalid validation (including the paperclip validation).

Also, you might need to specify :password_confirmation in your attributes.